# How to place a JSF flow in a subfolder?

Tags: jsf, directory, faces-flow

I'm introducing a JSF Faces flow into my application. This works, following the [oracle documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-configure003.htm#CHDGFCJF) But, only in the root folder.

Is it possible to place the JSF flow folder in a sub folder, else that root?

I can't get this working. That's all folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one myself.

A JSF flow definition can be done in 2 ways:

- with configuration file: flowname-flow.xml
- with configuration class: flowname.java

The first one can only define a flow-name, with the location defaulting to the root folder.

The second can define a location deeper in your folder structure.

***Configuration file example***: testflow.flow.xml

Only the id="testFlow" can be added to the definition, and *not the path.* This defaults to testFlow/testFlow.xhtml for the first page.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <flow-definition id="testFlow">
        <flow-return id="returnFromTestFlow">
            <from-outcome>#{testFlow.returnValue}</from-outcome>
        </flow-return>
    </flow-definition>
</faces-config>
```

***Configuration class example***: TestFlow.java

Add the *fully qualified path* to the view node within this flow.

```
public class TestFlow implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Produces
    @FlowDefinition
    public Flow defineFlow(@FlowBuilderParameter FlowBuilder flowBuilder) {

        String flowId = "testFlow";
        flowBuilder.id("", flowId);
        flowBuilder.viewNode(flowId, 
                "/other/location/flow/" + flowId + ".xhtml").
                markAsStartNode();
        flowBuilder.viewNode("testFlow2", "/other/location/flow/testFlow2.xhtml");
        flowBuilder.viewNode("testFlow3", "/other/location/flow/testFlow3.xhtml");
        ...
```

That's all folks!